# make this jQuery Ajax async=true with closure

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, closures

I wrote this object and I run it into the page I have:

```
var dataPage = {
  getData: function() { 
    return $.ajax({
      url: '/my_url/',
      data: {
        product: 'some_product',
        state: 'some_state'
      },
      type: 'POST',
      async: true,
      success: function (data) {
        //console.log(data);
        dataPage.results = data;
      },
      error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        alert('Error:' + xhr.status);
        alert(thrownError);
     }
   });
  }
  ,returnData: function(){
               var xhr = this.getData();
               //console.log(xhr);
               xhr.done(function() {
                     //console.log(xhr.responseText);
                     this.results = xhr.responseText;
                     $('#JSON').html(this.results);
                 });
            }
}

var results = dataPage.returnData()
console.log(results)
```

It works perfectly as the attribute `async` set to `false`: the data is loaded into the `div` with `id="JSON"`. The two `console.log()`s return the data and everything works fine.

Now I would like to switch to `async: true` but I don't know how to apply closure to make the function pass the resulting data correctly, avoiding the `xhr.responseText` to be `undefined` because of the asynchronous nature of the `getData()` call.

---

### EDITED

I edited the code above, added the `returnData()` function, but the last `console.log()` still return `undefined`. Adding the `.done()` didn't solve the problem of *taking out to the global scope* the results if `async: true`...

Comment: Simply move `$('#JSON').html(jqXHR.responseText);` to a place where you are sure the ajax request is already complete.

Comment: could you be more precise?

Comment: Sure, see JasonP's answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `done()` callback:

```
var jqXHR = dataPage.getData();
jqXHR.done(function(result) {
    $('#JSON').html(result);
});
```

Comment: you mean instead of `success`?

Comment: @tunedconsulting it doesn't have to be instead of success, you can have both.